# Google Play services complains to be out dated

Tags: android

And it's aparently not.

I've just compiled an APP with the latest google play services, which I've set on gradle as:

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

But when I open my APP, there's a huge warning.

[image]

And in LogCat:

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5208000 but found 5089070

If I open google play (pressing Actualizar button), I can see my Google Play services are totally updated.

This is happening on a genymotion emulator aswell as on a nexus 5 device.

I've tried things like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8'
```

However it complains:

> Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8.
>   Required by:
>       :mobile:unspecified > :BaseGameUtils:unspecified

Any tips?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fixed with

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

I've found out is that my Android Studio is downloading some version of google play services, which is not yet released on Google Play. That means that noone have that latest APK on their devices. So setting gradle to use an older version, will make the trick

Comment: Yes. What I've found out is that my Android Studio is downloading some version of google play services, which is not yet released on Google Play. That means that noone have that latest APK on their devices. So setting gradle to use an older version, will make the trick.

Comment: You should provide a more comprehensive answer then based on your comment. Someone might find it useful in future.

Comment: Placed that piece of comment into my answer =)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with
For Gradle:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
For Eclipse:
Add as library: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5077000_r18.zip

If above did not work, try to use older playstore service version of android playstore client.
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_4132530_r14.zip
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_4242030_r15.zip
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_4323030_r16.zip
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5077000_r18.zip
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_5089000_r19.zip
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_6171000_r21.zip